# How to make sum of two rows in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

The table has the values like,

```
   group_name    group_id    parent_group_id     amount

     One           69             10              1000
     Two           70             11              500
    Three          71             69              700
```

Here I need to make sum of the values in amount column if the `group id = 69`  matches with the `parent_group_id = 69` for which I have tried with

```
SUM(CASE WHEN fee_groups.groups_id = fee_groups.parent_fee_groups_id 
            THEN amount 
         ELSE 0 
     END) AS total
```

But above line doing nothing for me. If I am wrong with it then kindly help me to achieve the following result,

```
   group_name    group_id    parent_group_id     amount

     One           69             10              1700
     Two           70             11              500
```

Here the `group_id` and `parent_group_id` make a relationship, if there is a match from any of the `parent_group_id` with `group_id` then both are comes under single group and hence I need to sum both the values.

Comment: do you want the result of group_id on only or all the group_id

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal, If both the ids matches, say group_id with value 69 and parent_group_id with value 69 then it should get concatenated and the amount should get sum.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me to include `group_id` and `parent_group_id` given what you want to do.  You also don't explain what happens to the "71".

```
select min(group_name) as group_name,
       sum(amount)
from t
group by (case when 69 not in (group_id, parent_group_id) then group_name end);
```

This will combine the groups that share "69" and keep the others separate.

Comment: I need to make a sum of values based on matching of  ```groups_id``` with ```parent_fee_groups_id```.. Updated my question little..

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT t1.group_name, t1.group_id, t1.parent_group_id, 
      (t1.amount + IFNULL(t2.amount,0)) Amount
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 
ON t1.group_id = t2.parent_group_id 
OR t2.group_id = t1.parent_group_id
WHERE t1.group_name < t2.group_name OR t2.group_name IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.group_name, t1.group_id, t1.parent_group_id
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
group_name  group_id    parent_group_id   Amount
One         69           10               1700
Two         70           11               500
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
group_name,group_id,parent_group_id,
(CASE WHEN group_id = 69 THEN 
(amount+(SELECT amount FROM table1 WHERE parent_group_id = 69)) 
ELSE amount END) as new_amount 
FROM Table1 WHERE parent_group_id !=69;
```

Answer (score 0):

do the execute below query or this link

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6f38/13)

```
 select t.group_name,t.group_id,t.parent_group_id,
           (case when t.group_id = t1.parent_group_id then t1.amount + t.amount else t.amount end)
    from t 
    left join t as t1 on t.group_id = t1.parent_group_id
where t.group_id <>71
```

Comment: But i dont need to have the group ```three``` with group_id = 71 when it got added with the group ```one```..

Comment: But the value ```71``` will not be static  as the scenario is if there is a match then it will get added and the correspond group_id has match with parent_id twill get removed from the row.